# MySQL stored prosedure, INSERT INTO $table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, set, sql-insert, concatenation

I am trying to create a stored procedure to first create a table, if it doesn't already exist. This part function as intended:

```
    BEGIN
    SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ',`@variable_table`,' LIKE table_template;');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

After creating the table, or if the table already exist, i want the stored proseadure to dump a set of data in it.

```
    SET @sql = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ',`@variable_table`,' (
    `col1`,`col2`,`col3`,`col4`,`col5`)
    VALUES (
    `@D1`,`@D2`,`@D3`,`@D4`,`@D5`);');

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    END
```

If i exchange the ',`@variable_table`,' with existing_table_name the code works as intended.
Is it possible to run the code With a variable here and in that case, how do I do it?

Comment: You forgot to mention the problem you're facing with the existing code.

Comment: @stickybit I'm sorry, it returned a syntax error message and asked me to check the documentation.

Comment: [Edit] the question and include that message as **text**, no screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with trial and error for the past few hours I found the errors and the code is now working:

```
BEGIN
SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ',`@variable_table`,' LIKE table_template;');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

SET @sql = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ',`@variable_table`,' (`col1`,`col2`,`col3`,`col4`,`col5`)
VALUES ("',`@D1`,'","',`@D2`,'","',`@D3`,'","',`@D4`,'","',`@D5`,'");');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

It seems to me that my syntax error was in the '',``,"" area of the code.
As you can see, the only change I've made is to put the `@D1` variables outside the 'Text' and added " inside the text on both sides of the variables.

Answer (score 1):

The EXECUTE @stmt USING variables statement looks a little better:

```
BEGIN
SET @sql = CONCAT(
    'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ',`@variable_table`,' LIKE table_template;'
);
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

SET @sql = CONCAT(
    'INSERT INTO ',`@variable_table`,
    ' (`col1`,`col2`,`col3`,`col4`,`col5`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);'
);

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt USING @D1, @D2, @D3, @D4, @D5;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END;
```

Comment: Yes, it really does. Thank you for this!